# Create OS image that will work everywhere (virtual and physical)

Tags: virtual-machine, centos

I'm about to build a CentOS server for my project. In order to save me time, I would like to be able to copy this custom server so it can be duplicated quickly on physical servers and virtual ones (including online VPS such as Vultr and DigitalOcean).

What is the best strategy so I can create this ISO that would be easily installable everywhere?

By strategy, I mean should I create a physical server first or should I start with virtual? And how can I create this ISO after having installed my server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build a [kickstart](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/s1-kickstart2-file.html) file

The *full* process is a little too broad to fit into an answer (and there's a [gui](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Installation_Guide/ch-redhat-config-kickstart.html)) and use that to with pre and post install scripts to essentially automate the entire process.

You might also want to consider running the application in a *container* like [docker](https://www.docker.com/) either on its own, or in conjunction with your kickstarted iso - so you can package your dependancies and packages in one or more containers. I'm not a fan of this approach (since I'd like the option of setting things up bare metal) but this would give you maximum consistancy.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to utilize a virtualization technique to be able to make it work everywhere.

The reason I'm not suggesting an image is due to the fact that every targetted machine has different hardware. Virtualization removes this problem by using standard hardware inside the guest.

This means you will have to look into which virtualization platform you are going to use. This can be Microsoft Hyper-V, Oracle VM VirtualBox, VMWare, KVM, etc to name a few.

Depending on what development environment you have and what the servers are, you may be limited in your choice.

If you use windows as environment, then Hyper-V would be the way to go.

Virtualization platforms have a few files. 
They have a settings file (contains the settings for the virtual machine, and they have the container file which is the image of the attached harddisk.

You only need to copy the container file and can recreate the virtual machine as needed, suiting the host specs.

This means, installing the software if not already done, create a new virtual pc and instead of creating a new virtual harddisk, select existing and browse to your image. All should work out of the box.

If Hyper-V is not an option because you are not limited to windows only, Oracle VM can run on linux,mac and solaris too.

The biggest difference between hyper-v and oracle vm, is that hyper-v allows to only require resources when the guest actually needs them, whereas with oracle vm, it will reserve the resources when launching the vm, meaning you cannot run 2 vm's with each 8gb ram, if your system itself has 16gb ram. (the host needs ram too)

When you talk about servers, Windows Server comes with a core edition which is very lightweight and ideal to use as a base to host servers inside using Hyper-V. Microsoft even introduced Windows Nano Server which is designed to be as lightweight as possible allowing to host other servers using Hyper-V. The downside with Microsoft Windows Nano Server, is that it is very new (comes with Windows Server 2016) and requires lots of effort to get it to work. Also Nano server has a very basic interface by itself and requires remote management through powershell in order to manage it.

This is your strategy. I'm not sure how well it will work with Vultr and DigitalOcean as I have no experience with them nor do I know if they will allow this, but if they can't do it, there is basically no other way other than manually configuring those servers. You can ask if they use Hyper-V and are willing to mount your VHDX file for you.

Comment: Does it mean that it is not possible to create an ISO that can be installed in a virtual and non-virtual environments? I have read that some Linux distros support readapting to new environment...but your answer is centered exclusively on a virtual solution

Comment: Not to my knowledge, no.